# Why can I delete the file of another user given 640 permission and sticky bit?

Tags: permissions, file-permissions

I want to have a shared folder `/data` where multiple users can put their datasets to be used by others.

I've followed the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/313332/198237), so now I have:

```
ciprian@server /data $ ll .. | grep data
drwxrwsr-t   3 ciprian datasets  4096 Apr 28 09:53 data

ciprian@server /data $ ll
total 4
-rw-r----- 1 stan    datasets    0 Apr 28 09:53 stan-test
drwxr-s--- 2 ciprian datasets 4096 Apr 28 09:27 tdir
-rw-r----- 1 ciprian datasets    0 Apr 28 09:26 cip-test
```

So both users `stan` and `ciprian` have a test file, with owner `$USER:datasets` and 0640 permission. The parent directory `/data` belongs to `ciprian:datasets` and has permission `3775/drwxrwsr-t`. If I understand correctly, this means all files created will belong to group `datasets` and can only be deleted by their respective owner. In addition, given that each file has `0640` permission, users can read each others' files, but not write them (6 **4** 0).

So why can `ciprian` remove `stan-test` ?

Note that `stan` cannot remove `cip-test`, as they get 'Operation not permitted' error.

Is it because `ciprian` is owner of `/data` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the answer yourself; it's in the last paragraph. I looked up [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) and found:

> "only the file's owner, **the directory's owner**, or root can rename or delete the file".